# Java Ragged Array, trying to display multiple Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble finding out what is the issue with my code,  Everything is fine till I get to the Jagged array. I want it to display the code as a jagged array but I dont know

```
package ajk;

public class Test2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        int[][] twoD = {
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4, 5},
            {6},
            {7, 8, 9},
        };
        printArray(twoD); 
    }
    public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
        System.out.println("[");

        int r = 4;
        int c = 3;
        int i, j;
    
        for (i=0; i < r; i++ );
            System.out.print("["); 
            for (j=0; j < c; j++ ) {
                System.out.print( arr[i][j]  + " " );
            }
        }
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Use `j < arr[i].length` instead of `j < c`

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "a jagged".

Comment: @CardinalSystem Jagged Array

Comment: @4castle Tried doing that, Just comes up with my opening square brackets

Comment: @AndrewKramer is that another name for a 2d array?

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors and mistakes:

- `for (i=0; i < r; i++ );`You can not use for loop like this. You have to write your code in the braces
- Your array's column sizes are different from each other, so you can not determine the column size with one variable. Best way is `array[i].length` for this situation
- You can define i and j inside the parantez of the for loop.

If you change the code as below: it will run

```
public class Test2
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] twoD = {
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4, 5},
            {6},
            {7, 8, 9},
    };
    printArray(twoD);
}
    public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
        System.out.println("[");

        for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++ ) {
                System.out.print( arr[i][j]  + " " );
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are making some mistakes in your code**

1.Always put the code of for loop in curly braces like this `for(){}`

2.You are making a general mistake by making the array index out of bounds for that you should use `array[i].length` to make sure column size are not different from each other

3.your code should look like this so change and try the code below

```
 public class Test2    
 {

public static void main(String[] args){
int[][] twoD = {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {6},
        {7, 8, 9}
};
Test2.printArray(twoD); 
}
public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
System.out.println("[");

int r = 4;
int c = 3;
int i, j,a=0;

for(i=0; i<r; i++ ){
System.out.print("["); 
for (j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++ ) {
    System.out.print( arr[i][j]  + " " );

}
System.out.println("]");
 }
 }
}
```

**And**

I have also added another square bracket for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

It' quite simple, actually. Arrays class have some static methods to print its own elements (ints, doubles, Objects, etc.). Since, here is two dimensional array, in the loop you go through every element of the arr (which is an array of int), and call this method. Arrays.toString(someArr) represents someArr as a String.

```
for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
    int[] arr1D = arr[row];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1D));
}
```

Comment: Add some description for this answer please

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov It' quite simple, actually. Arrays class have some static methods to print its own elements (ints, doubles, Objects, etc.). Since, here is two dimensional array, in the loop you go through every element of the arr (which is an array of int), and call this method...

Comment: More precisely, Arrays.toString(int [] array) represents array as a String

Comment: @zlakad Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47626701/edit) to add the explanation, do not put it in comments.